# Wait is being ignored by code and passing straight through on Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android

I need to open my popup screen when my method is called, but it is being ignored by my await and does not show the popup.

This is for an android device and I am using `rg.plugins.popup` to display my popup page and I'm using VS17 as the IDE.

So far I've also tried calling my method synchronously but that doesn't seem to work either.

```
public async void PegaValor(bool retry)
{
    await PopupNavigation.PushAsync(new Paginas.PopupTentarNovamente());

    Paginas.PopupTentarNovamente tentarNovamente = new Paginas.PopupTentarNovamente();
    if (tentarNovamente.resultado)
    {
        retry = false;
    }
    else
    {
        retry = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please pop the code you use above that calls the method PegaValor so that we can see how you're using it. The odds are that the plugin needs to be ran on the main UI dispatcher, but I just want to confirm how you're calling it before I provide an answer.

Comment: I have a loop of five tries, after then i call the method.
basically is a if/else and when i'm on else i have: else { PegaValor(retry);}
The "retry" is a bool that the initial value is true

Comment: @Gustavo,According to your code, what is Paginas.PopupTentarNovamente? It is a page? I install rg.plugins.popup, it can display succeeefully, here is the sample about popup:https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/learn-about-xamarin-forms-popup/

Comment: @CherryBu, Pages is a folder inside my project, Popup Trying Again is a page rg.plugin.popup, my problem is that the page does not appear when passing through the code, it only goes up when the method ends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a suspicion that the pop up needs to be ran on the main UI Dispatcher, I'd suggest trying the following:

```
public async void PegaValor(bool retry)
{
    Activity.RunOnUiThread(async () => {
        await PopupNavigation.PushAsync(new Paginas.PopupTentarNovamente());
    });

    Paginas.PopupTentarNovamente tentarNovamente = new Paginas.PopupTentarNovamente();
    if (tentarNovamente.resultado)
    {
        retry = false;
    }
    else
    {
        retry = true;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Based on your comments and taking a quick look at your github link here are a couple of ways you can do what I suggested, although I still have no clue how your instantiating the class from the git repo.

So for a quick example, this way assumes your using that class inside of an activity, so you could try the following

```
// Create an instance of metodosEmpenho in your activity and pass through the Activity as a parameter to the constructor.

public class MyActivity : Activity
{
    private MetodosEmpenho metodosEmpenho;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        metodosEmpenho = new MetodosEmpenho(Context as Activity);
        metodosEmpenho.VerOperador("");
    }
}

// Create a consturctor in the MetodosEmpenho class that will take the Activity paramter and store it for later use.

public class MetodosEmpenho
{
    private readonly Activity _activity

    public MetodosEmpenho(Activity currActivity)
    {
        _activity = currActivity;
    }

    public async void PegaValor(bool retry)
    {
        _activity.RunOnUiThread(async () => {
            await PopupNavigation.PushAsync(new Paginas.PopupTentarNovamente());
        });

        Paginas.PopupTentarNovamente tentarNovamente = new Paginas.PopupTentarNovamente();
        if (tentarNovamente.resultado)
        {
            retry = false;
        }
        else
        {
            retry = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: probably it would work, but the method is inside a class, not on a content page, 
I don't think I was clear about that, sorry

Comment: @GustavoAveiro in that case I could do with you putting more of your code in your post, because I suspect you need to pass through the activity so that you can ensure it's getting rendered by the main dispatcher.

Comment: Here i have the complete code of the class: https://github.com/AveiroKing/ProgramsAndTests/blob/master/Metodosempenho.cs
the only thing isn't there is the call of the class, is just a simple call after some condition.

Comment: @GustavoAveiro yep ok, looking at that I think it's best to pass through the current Activity or Context that calls or uses the class through and then use my suggestion above.

Comment: Right, but how exactly can i do this? do you have any model?

Comment: @GustavoAveiro guides on how to pass a parameter through to a class can be found everywhere.

Comment: @GustavoAveiro see revised answer.

Comment: I tried it on my MainActivity and got this error " 'Activity' is a type, which is not valid in the given context ", any idea?

Comment: @GustavoAveiro yep you can use 'Context as Activity' I've adjusted my answer above.